# How to move a rect together with its associated drawing (Pygame)?

Tags: python, pygame, drawing, rectangles

Minimal working example:

```
x = pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x, y), radius, width)
x.center = (my_wanted_center_x, my_wanted_center_y)
```

Then after updating the display, it's always displayed at its original location. Tried with other figures as well. Neither does `x.move()` work. How do I move any drawn figure in a simplest way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to store the position of your object, update the rect's attributes (for example `.x` or `.center`) in the while loop and then draw your circle or image/surface at the `rect.center` position.

```
import pygame as pg

pg.init()

screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
clock = pg.time.Clock()
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')
SIENNA = pg.Color('sienna1')
radius = 20
# This rect serves as the position of the circle and
# can be used for collision detection.
rect = pg.Rect(50, 200, radius, radius)

done = False
while not done:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            done = True

    rect.x += 1  # Update the position of the rect.

    screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
    # Now draw the circle at the center of the rect.
    pg.draw.circle(screen, SIENNA, rect.center, radius)
    pg.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pg.quit()
```